# Post a data/image to facebook wall using access token in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

My question is pretty tricky, how to post data/image to facebook using already created access token.

1. User will login to his account for the first time and get `access_token` and `user_id` stored in server/local database.
2. User will logged out of the app.
3. Next time without log into to his account only using with pre saved `access_token` (or) `user_id` I need post image on facebook wall.

I tried my level best but didn't get any related help.

Please suggest something before casting downvote!!

Comment: you should check the access_token on existing before make the request. If it's nil then login. Also you should check the permissions.

Comment: so is it possible if the access_token is active?

Comment: ofc, if access_token active it is possible, but access_token can be expired you should check the expirationDate of the token and update it.